# Typecasting a pointer to undefined type doesn't produce compiler error

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, casting

I was writing a socket program and I mistyped the `struct sockaddr_in` as `struct sockaddrr_in` (notice an extra `r`), but I didn't receive any compiler error only `incompatible-pointer-types` warning.

Here is a minimal reproducible program to demonstrate the issue.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct Addr {
    int flat_no;
};

struct Person {
    struct Addr *address;
};

int main()
{
    struct Person p;
    struct Addr addr;
    p.address = &addr;
    struct Person *ptr = &p;
    struct Addr *a = (struct Addrr *)ptr->address; // struct Addr mistyped as Addrr
    printf("no error!!");
}
```

Both `gcc` and `clang` produce this warning:

```c
<source>:20:22: warning: initialization of 'struct Addr *' from incompatible pointer type 'struct Addrr *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   20 |     struct Addr *a = (struct Addrr *)ptr->address;
      |                      ^
```

Since `struct Addrr` is never defined in the program, how the compiler is able to resolve the mistyped symbol? What is the effect of typecasting `ptr->address` to an undefined type `struct Addrr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the cast is the first time `struct Addrr` appears, it acts as a declaration of that type.  The type is incomplete because it has no definition, but you can still create a pointer to an incomplete type.

So while you do get the warning about converting between incompatible pointer types, you don't get an error about the other type.

Answer (score 2):

The cast operator is defined the following way

```
cast-expression:
    unary-expression
    ( type-name ) cast-expression
```

`struct Addrr *` is a pointer type. Pointer types are always complete types. Though the pointed type `struct Addrr` is an incomplete type.